# Poisson or Binomial?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a fabric company, the fixed probability of a machine producing a bad fabric is $p$ independent on the fabric previously produced.
At the output of the machine, $n$ fabrics are taken at random. $X$ is the random variable equal to the number of bad fabrics in a selection of $n$ fabrics at the mouth of the machine.

- What probability distribution law does $X$ follow and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fits perfectly the definition of a binomial distribution. There are $n$ independent trials, and in each trial the probability of "success," if you can call it success, is $p$. It is exactly like tossing a funny coin $n$ times, with the probability of a head equal to $p$, and our random variable the number of heads.

To put it another way, let $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th fabric is defective, and $0$ if it is not. Then
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$
and the sum of $n$ independent identically distributed Bernoulli random variables has binomial distribution.

**Remark:** There is **some** connection with the Poisson. If $n$ is large and $p$ is small, with $np$ of modest size, then the binomial distribution of this problem is well-approximated by the Poisson with parameter $\lambda=np$. But it is still a binomial.

Comment: I understand this, but in my question, one only needs the number of  defective fabrics whatever the order of arrangement. Unless what was considered was the order at which the fabrics come out of the machine?

Comment: The Binomial distribution measures the number of successes. The probability that $X=k$ is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. It is true that when we **derive** this formula, we consider all the possible orders in which the successes and/or failures could occur.

Comment: so where does this "order" that was considered falls in my question. Is it at the selection of the fabrics from the mouth of the machine or  is it the order at which the fabrics came out of the machine?

Comment: It is an **arbitrary** order. After we have chosen our $n$ fabrics, we line them up in a row **without** testing them for quality. But remember, this is how we derive the formula. Once we have derived the formula, we need not consider order at all.

Comment: I guess I just have to accept it that way. Even if the order is arbitrary, it is at least acceptable. Thank you for your answer and time.

Answer (score 0):

Defective vs. not defective usually implies binomial. If $n$ is sufficiently large and $p$ (probability of success) is very small, the Poisson distribution can be used to approximate the binomial distribution.

Comment: Use binomial when each observation is one of two possible outcomes, e.g. a random sample of size $n$ is drawn and the number of defects found in the sample is recorded. Use Poisson when dealing with rates of occurrence e.g. if the number of defects per length of fabric exceeds $L$ then etc.

Answer (score 0):

Binomial would be more appropriate here. See the machine has a Bernoulli trial that has succes probability $p$. Because of independance, each of the $n$ fabrics you took have a $p$ chance of being bad. The number of bad fabrics is then given by the binomial distribution.

Poisson would give you an approximation of this, but $n$ would have to be large enough, and $np$ small enough.

Poisson distribution are more related to problems of the type :
A machine produces fabrics at random. In $5$ minutes, it produces on average $3$ fabrics. What is the probability that you have $5$ bad fabrics after $10$ minutes?

Comment: but doesn't binomial always consider the arrangement of the fabric?

Comment: What do you mean by arrangement?

Comment: sorry. what i meant was that the order of selection is put into consideration when using binomial.

Comment: Unless you know any kind of information about the fabrics before taking your sample, you can imagine your sample as soon as it come out of the machine, as i the experience had just been realized. If however you wait the end of the day, you know that the machine produced say $k$ bad fabrics and you take a sample of $n$,then $X$ will be Hypergeometric

Comment: I understand you but you didn't answer my question. When binomial is used, the order of selection is always considered which I don't see in this case.

Comment: The binomial is only used to count the number of succes in a experiment. The order you mention is only really to count all strings of lenght $n$ of the form GGBBBG...GGB where G is good and B is bad fabrics

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6255/discussion-between-fola-yinka-and-jean-sebastien)

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: I was also downvoted. Have upvoted to cancel the incorrect downvote. Presumably the downvoter is of the opinion that the Poisson model is better. Perhaps there is confusion with the *number* of imperfections in a randomly chosen piece of cloth. But that's a different problem.

Comment: Upvoted in return, thanks. If at least we had had some explanation